# Abrir um modal que vem de uma pagina diferente PHP

Tags: php, modal, bootstrap-4

Quero abrir um modal em um botão de um menu mas só que coloquei ele em uma arquivo separada só pra ele, 
queria saber qual o comando que dá para abrir ele puxando de outro aquivo em PHP

Comment: Mas nesse arquivo separado só tem o o código html do modal?

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso dessa forma.

> index.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <button type='button'  onclick='abreModal()' >Abrir</button>

<div class="modal"></div>

    //Ajax
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function abreModal(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        //Caminho do arquivo do seu modal
        url: 'pasta/modal.html',
        success: function(data){              
          $('.modal').html(data);
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

> ```
> Arquivo modal.html
> ```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" width="100%">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <label class="modal-title">Modal</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Conteudo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect"  data-dismiss="modal">FECHAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iframe provavelmente é a solução (provavelmente combinado com `.embed-responsive`):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="url-da-pagina.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

Algo como:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="URL-DA-PAGINA.PHP"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentação:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

---

Exemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Exibir
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="URL-DA-PAGINA.PHP"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Abrindo links no iframe

Se deseja abrir links no iframe pode fazer um evento com jQuery (bootstrap usa jQuery)

> Exemplo no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8dumLrcx/2/

assim:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //carrega URL do link no IFRAME
    $("#iframeModal").attr("src", this.href);
});
```

O HTML seria isto:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="pagina1.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 1
</a> |
<a href="pagina2.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 2
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe id="iframeModal" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Abrindo links com Ajax (`$().load()`)

Para não precisar importar os resources (.js e .css) dentro do IFRAME pode usar Ajax, no caso a função `$().load()` deve resolver o seu problema, deve ficar assim o código (é sem iframe):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //carrega URL do link com Ajax
    $("#modal-conteudo").load(this.href);
});
```

Leve em consideração que os links devem conter apenas o HTML, sem o `<head>`, é apenas para carregar dentro do modal, como se tivesse sido carregado via `include` (semelhante, mas claro que são requisições HTTP diferentes)

O HTML seria isto:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="pagina1.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 1
</a> |
<a href="pagina2.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 2
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="modal-conteudo" class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pagina que eu quis dizer é arquivo é tipo um include mas é no href nao sei como faz

Comment: @BrunoAlbuquerque não sei se entendi direito, mas se for o que eu entendi, vocÊ esta confundindo, PHP é back-end, sendo assim include é executado no back-end, quando chega no front-end chega tudo já processado no formato HTML, não tem como executar um include no front-end, sites funciona com comunicação HTTP, ou seja é cliente e servidor, depois que baixou a página o PHP já foi executado, não tem como voltar no tempo. O que poderia fazer é usar IFRAME mesmo ou usar Ajax, vou formular um pequeno exemplo.

Comment: <a data-toggle="modal" href="modalhorario.php?"> tipo assim mas nao esta dando certo o modal esta em um arquivo diferente

Comment: @BrunoAlbuquerque veja o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/8dumLrcx/2/, basta adaptar para algo como `<a href="pagina1.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 1
</a> |
<a href="pagina2.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Página 2
</a>`

Comment: @BrunoAlbuquerque adicionei um exemplo com Ajax do jQuery (.load) também, veja as edições da resposta